# Complex update with three tables involved

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgresql in my company as a primary store and I'm struggling to implement an update query involving three different tables.

Here is the schema :

- Table 1 has entity_id, entity_type and company_id (referencing Company.id) columns.
- Company has id column
- Special_company has id (which corresponds to Table1.entity_id) and company_id (referencing Company.id)

I would like to update all the rows of Table 1 where `Table1.entity_type = 'SpecialCompany'` in order to fill `Table1.company_id` such that  :

`Table1.entity_id = SpecialCompany.id and SpecialCompany.company_id = Company.id`

I've started something like that:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET company_id = (select c.id 
                  FROM company c 
                  INNER JOIN special_company w ON c.id=w.company_id 
                  WHERE w.id=709) 
WHERE entity_type='SpecialCompany' AND entity_id=709;
```

But I am not able to replace `709` by all the `Table1.entity_id` where `Table1.entity_type = 'SpecialCompany'`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering to my question as I found the solution :

`UPDATE Table1 t
SET company_id = c.id
FROM Company c

    INNER JOIN special_company w ON c.id=w.company_id
WHERE 
    t.entity_type = 'SpecialCompany' AND t.entity_id=w.id;`

Thanks @Krishna for your help !

Comment: I didnt get time to look into this. my query works in MSSQL. I didnt realize it was for Postgre. sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for something like this.

```
update  t
set t.company_id=c.id
from 
 Company C 
 INNER JOIN special_company w ON c.id=w.company_id 
 INNER JOIN Table1 t on t.entity_id=w.entity_id
 Where t.entity_type = 'SpecialCompany'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Doing this, gives me an error in the first line : ```UPDATE t SET 
               ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "t" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 112```